# Grouping data in SQL Server by multiple references

Tags: sql-server

```css
Store    Grupa Quantity  Value          ITTYPE
1         A1 -44128       -101409.6          100
1         B1 -50000        -1500             101
1         E1 -32560       -53720.62     100
1         C1 -54730       -29006.9          101
1         D1 -45720       -37033.2          101
1         E1 -370500       -171100.61  100
2         E1 -370500       -227038.7          101
2         C1 -37152       -18575.94          100
2         C1 -145980       -52261.57          100
2         B1 -75600       -40639.65       100
2         B1 -69750       -64170          100
```

And I want a grouping by Store and Grupa

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

And I want a grouping by Store and Grupa

```css
ITTYPE                  100             100           101       101
Store    Grupa   Quantity         Value         Quantity   Value
 1        A1   -44,128.00      -101,409.60       -         -       
 1        B1             -         -         -50,000.00   -1,500.00     
 1             C1             -         -         -54,730.00    -29,006.90     
 1             D1             -          -          -45,720.00   -37,033.20     
 1        E1   -403,060.00      -224,821.23       -         -       
 2        A1          -               -            -         -       
 2        B1    -145,350.00      -104,809.65       -         -       
 2             C1    -183,132.00      -70,837.51         -         -       
 2        D1          -               -            -         -       
 2        E1          -               -        -370,500.00    -227,038.70
```

IT's like a sumifs by Store, Grupa and also by ITTYPE

Comment: You should post some code.  But maybe a 'grouping set' is what you could use?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
WITH RawData AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Store, 'A1' AS Grupa, -44128 AS Quantity, -101409.6 AS [Value], 100 AS ITTYPE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'B1', -50000, -1500, 101
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'E1', -32560, -53720.62, 100
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'C1', -54730, -29006.9, 101
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D1', -45720, -37033.2, 101
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'E1', -370500, -171100.61, 100
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'E1', -370500, -227038.7, 101
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'C1', -37152, -18575.94, 100
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'C1', -145980, -52261.57, 100
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B1', -75600, -40639.65, 100
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B1', -69750, -64170, 100),
Store AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM RawData),
Grupa AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Grupa FROM RawData)
SELECT
    s.Store,
    g.Grupa,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.ITTYPE = 100 THEN r.Quantity END) AS [100_Quantity],
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.ITTYPE = 100 THEN r.[Value] END) AS [100_Value],
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.ITTYPE = 101 THEN r.Quantity END) AS [101_Quantity],
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.ITTYPE = 101 THEN r.[Value] END) AS [101_Value]
FROM
    Store s
    CROSS JOIN Grupa g
    LEFT JOIN RawData r ON r.Store = s.Store AND r.Grupa = g.Grupa
GROUP BY
    s.Store,
    g.Grupa
ORDER BY
    1,2;
```

Noting that if you have more ITTYPES than 100 and 101 then you might be better off with a dynamic PIVOT?

Results are:

```
Store   Grupa   100_Quantity    100_Value   101_Quantity    101_Value
1       A1      -44128          -101409.60  NULL            NULL
1       B1      NULL            NULL        -50000          -1500.00
1       C1      NULL            NULL        -54730          -29006.90
1       D1      NULL            NULL        -45720          -37033.20
1       E1      -403060         -224821.23  NULL            NULL
2       A1      NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
2       B1      -145350         -104809.65  NULL            NULL
2       C1      -183132         -70837.51   NULL            NULL
2       D1      NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
2       E1      NULL            NULL        -370500         -227038.70
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
Store INT,Grupa NVARCHAR(5), Quantity DECIMAL(10,2), Value DECIMAL(10,2), ITTYPE INT)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(1         ,'A1',   -44128        ,-101409.6     ,100),
(1         ,'B1',   -50000        ,-1500         ,101),
(1         ,'E1',   -32560        ,-53720.62     ,100),
(1         ,'C1',   -54730        ,-29006.9      ,101),
(1         ,'D1',   -45720        ,-37033.2      ,101),
(1         ,'E1',   -370500       ,-171100.61    ,100),
(2         ,'E1',   -370500       ,-227038.7     ,101),
(2         ,'C1',   -37152        ,-18575.94     ,100),
(2         ,'C1',   -145980       ,-52261.57     ,100),
(2         ,'B1',   -75600        ,-40639.65     ,100),
(2         ,'B1',   -69750        ,-64170        ,100)

SELECT Store ITTYPE,Grupa Grupa,SUM(CASE WHEN ITTYPE = 100 THEN Quantity ELSE '0' END) Quantity,
                                SUM(CASE WHEN ITTYPE = 100 THEN Value ELSE '0' END) Value,
                                SUM(CASE WHEN ITTYPE = 101 THEN Quantity ELSE '0' END) Quantity,
                                SUM(CASE WHEN ITTYPE = 101 THEN Value ELSE '0' END) Value
FROM @table GROUP BY Store,Grupa ORDER BY Store,Grupa
```

Hope it helps. :)